# sharepoint 2010 search.asmx query Problem

Tags: jquery, web-services

I use below query for people search in sharepoint 2010 using jquery

```
 SELECT PREFERREDNAME,FirstName,LastName,JobTitle,Department,Email,WorkEmail,WorkPhone,Skills,PictureUrl,Path,Rank,MobilePhone FROM scope() where \"SCOPE\"='People' AND ((\"JobTitle\" LIKE '%" + lastName + "%') OR (\"Skills\" LIKE '%" + lastName + "%') OR (\"LastName\" LIKE '%" + lastName + "%') OR (\"FirstName\" LIKE '%" + lastName + "%') OR (\"Department\" LIKE '%" + lastName + "%') OR (\"Email\" LIKE '%" + lastName + "%')  OR (\"WorkEmail\" LIKE '%" + lastName + "%')  OR  (\"PreferredName\" LIKE '%" + lastName + "%'))
```

But when i add workphone in where condition like that

```
          (\"WorkPhone\" LIKE '%" + lastName + "%')
```

It stop return results and
Display error No result Found.
I also apply change according to following link.
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sharepointsearch/thread/598c16f8-bc13-4561-b6d7-e2981dda260f
Please Help me.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got My solution from following site

http://kgraeme.wordpress.com/2010/07/28/sharepoint-user-profile-custom-properties-keyword-search-problem/

this Link follow us how we use custom property of user in search service.

But for default property U use in your searching U have to check following thing

go to Central Admin>Search Service>Metadata Properties> Find your properties Edit them and select option **Allow this property to be used in scope** and start full crawls .

Happy searching .....