# FullTextSqlQuery. multy language search

Tags: search, people-search

I tried to use FullTextSqlQuery for people search. This is my code:

```
FullTextSqlQuery q = new FullTextSqlQuery(SPContext.Current.Site);
q.ResultTypes = ResultType.RelevantResults;
q.QueryText = "SELECT PreferredName, AccountName, JobTitle FROM SCOPE() WHERE \"scope\" = 'People' AND CONTAINS(JobTitle, 'test')";
ResultTableCollection tables = q.Execute();
ResultTable results = tables[ResultType.RelevantResults];
```

It works fine, but if I use search word in Russian language, the result table is empty.

```
"SELECT PreferredName, AccountName, JobTitle FROM SCOPE() WHERE \"scope\" = 'People' AND CONTAINS(JobTitle, 'тест')"
```

I found that CONTAINS function has LCID parameter and I tried use it, but I did not have any luck.

```
"SELECT PreferredName, AccountName, JobTitle FROM SCOPE() WHERE \"scope\" = 'People' AND CONTAINS(JobTitle, 'тест', 1049)"
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Have you tried to setup [Culture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.search.query.query.culture.aspx) property?

Comment: yes, I tried...

Comment: @Kai, I think that I miss something in search service settings. But I do not have any idea what can it be (((

Comment: I am not sure this is your problem but you can try to configure this please check http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/27241/sharepoint-2010-search-asmx-query-problem/27268#27268

Comment: @V_B this solution is not helpful for me (

Comment: don't know if this article is one that you have seen or not, but I did wonder if it would help: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa981341.aspx also - have you tried using an out-of-the-box search component using Russian on the server to ensure it will work and has been set up correctly?

Comment: Hi, did you manage to find the solution to this?

Comment: @FalakMahmood, no :(

Comment: If you are using SP2010, did you try with keyword query? FTSQL is kind of depricated and often hard to work with. Keyword query is the way to go :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this explanation:

> SQL Server 2000 and SQL Server 2005 full-text search supports only one
>   language for each database. If you are supporting Windows SharePoint
>   Services Web sites in several languages and you want to enable
>   full-text search in those languages, consider hosting each language on
>   a separate virtual server with a separate database per language.

Fool text of the post can be found by [this link](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-sharepoint-services-it/managing-and-customizing-search-HA001160797.aspx).

Comment: you can feel free to mark this as the answer. It answers the question for me!